# How to use the node media server npm module with auth for publish and play streamings?

Tags: node.js, npm, stream, node-media-server

How to use auth for play and publish streams?
How to send the user pass params using Larix Software or by URL?
How to use the URL to send auth data?

Example:

```
    auth: {
        play: true,
        publish: true,
        api: true,
        api_user: "user",
        api_pass: "pass",
    },
```

rtmp://user:pass@localhost:port:/live/stream